# MarkLogic: Timeout for processing document to add properties

Tags: xquery, marklogic

MarkLogic: 9.8.0

We around 20M of data and now we need to add additional data into document properties.

So we have setup scheduler & below code will be executed

```
let $Log := xdmp:log("[ Project ][ Scheduler ][ Start ][ ======================== Insert Records Scheduler Start ======================== ]")

for $author in (/author][not(property::root/contributors)])[1 to 500]

let $uri           := $author/base-uri()
let $auth_element  := if ($author/aug)
                      then
                           for $auth in $author/aug/pname
                               let $snm := $auth/snm/text()
                               let $fnm := fn:concat(fn:string-join(for $i in $auth/fnm return $i,' '),'')
                               return
                                     <pname type='author'>{fn:normalize-space(fn:concat($snm,' ',$fnm))}</pname>
                      else if ($author/editg)
                      then
                           for $auth in $author/pname
                               let $snm := $auth/snm/text()
                               let $fnm := fn:concat(fn:string-join(for $i in $auth/fnm return $i,' '),'')
                               return
                                     <pname type='editor'>{fn:normalize-space(fn:concat($snm,' ',$fnm))}</pname>
                      else ()
let $XmlDoc := <root><contributors>{$auth_element}</contributors></root>             
        
return try{
            xdmp:document-add-properties($uri,$XmlDoc),
            xdmp:log("[ InspecDirect ][ Scheduler ][ End ][ ======================== Insert Records Scheduler End ======================== ]")
            }
       catch($e){xdmp:log($e)}
```

When we change from [1 to 500] to [1 to 10000] we are getting timeout error here.
And if we will go with 500 then it will take weeks to finish it.

Can you please let me know if this approach is fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Corb2](https://developer.marklogic.com/code/corb/) would probably be a better solution.  You can take your current XQuery and split it into two pieces.  The first piece would gather the URIs that need to be updated.

The second piece takes the URI as input, and processes it accordingly.  This allows for very large batches to be processed without timeouts.

[Corb2 Wiki](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/wiki)

[Corb2 Github](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2)

Comment: The code in the question attacks the problem with a single thread. Corb2 will break the workload into many small batches, and run a configurable number of threads to process them in parallel. Processing 20 million records should be no sweat for Corb2..

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the DHF 5 Framework provided by MarkLogic in which you can manage the count of documents processed in a batch by giving batch size and also thread size which will take care of running the process parallelly and efficiently. This framework will help you to reduce your timeout errors.

https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.2/